# Looks like gifsicle is not installed in the usr/bin/ folder. How can I install it?

Tags: php, imagemagick, gif, animated-gif, imagemagick-convert

First off, I see `convert` but not `gifsicle` in the `usr/bin/`. Am I looking in the wrong place?

I want to compress animated GIFs using https://pornel.net/lossygif but it needs gifsicle to work.

so far i've gotten:
`exec("convert $animation -coalesce -gravity SouthWest  -geometry +0+0 null: $watermark -layers composite -layers optimize $animation");` to work...

now after that, i want to be able to compress that image: `exec("gifsicle -O3 --lossy=80 -o $animation $animation");`

Comment: I think you mean `/usr/bin/`, try that instead of `usr/bin/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are instructions on the `gifsicle` github page: https://github.com/kohler/gifsicle. depending on your server you might try:

```
yum install gifsicle
```

Comment: i tried `yum install gifsicle` but server replied with `You need to be root to perform this command` i might add that im on a shared server with Arvixe

Comment: @JeromieDevera SUDO BANG BANG